# Apache Virtual Hosts Non-www not working

Tags: apache, centos, centos7, virtual-hosts

I'm setting up a Virtual Hosts file on my CentOS 7 box and I'm having trouble getting my domain to resolve correctly.

Here's what my current `/etc/httpd/conf.d/vhost.conf` file looks like

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.com
   ServerName www.domain.com
   ServerAlias domain.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain.com/public_html/
   ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error.log
   CustomLog /var/log/httpd/access.log combined

   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.domain.com [OR]
   RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =domain.com
   RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

It seems the the correct redirects are happening. For exmaple:

domain.com redirects to https: //www.domain.com
www works fine

BUT

https: //domain.com doesn't work
http ://domain.com doesn't work

In fact, if I remove the redirects I have set, domain.com ins't working at all, so it looks like the ServerAlias is broken?

I'm wondering if I need another redirect or is there some other step I'm missing?

Also, don't mind the spaces between http and the domain name. StackOverflow made me format it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue. I had my local hosts file configured to point to an old out of date IP address……

`domain.com *bad ip address*`

I'm so embarrassed. I must have set that up months ago and forgot.

Answer (score 0):

As presented, no request to anything `https` will ever work.  Normal, you only have a `VirtualHost` on port 80.  You do have a `Listen` directive for that port right?

For your redirections.  It says: if you ask for `http://www.example.com` or `http://example.com`, redirect to `https://<WHAT THE USER ASKED FOR>`.  In essence you are forcing your users to use https all the time, no problem there.  But you do not have a `VirtualHost` on port 443, hence no response.

So:

```
Listen *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com

    ErrorLog  /var/log/httpd/80_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/80_access.log combined

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>

Listen *:443
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.example.com
    # in case users do directly to https
    ServerAlias example.com    

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain.com/public_html/
    DocumentIndex index.html

    ErrorLog  /var/log/httpd/443_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/443_access.log combined

    # SSL CONFIGURATIONS, TODO!
</VirtualHost>
```

- In your *:443 VH, you will have to configure certificates and SSL.
- Your certificates will have to be valid for *both* www.example.com and example.com to avoid browser complaints.
- Careful there might be an ssl.conf included file under conf.d that defines some of this.  Make sure you only set it once to avoid confusion.
- No need to define `DocumentRoot` in *:80 VH since it only redirects and does not respond content to client.

Have fun!